# Zend framework2 - form input fields, using them with jquery

Tags: jquery, zend-framework2

In my html file I am rendering the form like this,

```
<div id="wizard" class="swMain">
  <div id="step-1">
    <strong>Name:</strong><br />
    <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('firstname')); ?>
  </div>
  <div id="step-2">
    <strong>Last name</strong><br />
        <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('lastname')); ?>

    <strong>Company name</strong><br />
    <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('companyname')); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to be able to display first name, last name and company name here

```
<div>
    <div id="lp-firstname"></div>
    <div id="lp-lastname"></div>
    <div id="lp-companyname"></div>
</div>
```

so I am using script like this,

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          var firstnameNode = $('#lp-firstname'),
              lastnameNode = $('#lp-lastname'),
              companynameNode = $('#lp-companyname'),
              firstname = $('#firstname'),
              lastname = $('#lastname'),
              companyname = $('#companyname');

          $('#wizard input, #wizard textarea').bind('blur keyup',function() {
              //name & websites
              if($('#firstname').val()) {
                      firstnameNode.text(firstname.val());
              }
              if($('#lastname').val()) {
                      lastnameNode.text(lastname.val());
              }
              if($('#companyname').val()) {
                      companynameNode.text(companyname.val());
              }
          });
      });
</script>
```

But I am not able to display anything, I am not sure may be I am doing something wrong here, But while using the same code with using

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="" class="input" />
```

instead of

```
<?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('firstname')); ?>
```

works fine with me, Can some one help me out on how to do this in Zend framework2 form fields.
The label names for form fields are the same as I have written here.

Comment: I tried `if($('#firstname').val() !== '')` but not working for me...

Comment: Did you check the sourcecode? You're able to overwrite the ID - check if the rendered HTML is really what you expect it to be.

Comment: exactly @sam that was the problem, I was using id now using name like this `input[name*="companyname"]`  it fixed the problem.

Comment: For JS Purposes the ID may be the best fit though. Just be sure to assign your FormElements with an ID `'attributes' => array( 'id' => 'myid')`